# need to understand thread(this, ThreadName) in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class GetCurrentThread implements Runnable {
   Thread th;

   public GetCurrentThread(String threadName) {
      th = new Thread(this,threadName); //<----DOUBT 
      System.out.println("get threadname "+th.getName());
      th.start();
   }

  public void run() {
     System.out.println(th.getName()+" is starting.....");
     System.out.println("Current thread name : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
     System.out.println("Current thread name : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
     new GetCurrentThread("1st Thread");
     //new GetCurrentThread("2nd Thread");
   }
}
```

Can someone explain what the 2nd line of above code is doing?
My understanding for "th = new Thread(this,threadName)" is, it will create thread object with the name given; let say name "1st Thread".Now, What "this" keyword is doing here?because when i remove this and try get name of the thread I got the name with no issues, but it never started run().can someone explain in simple terms rather than with one single line answer. i really appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: See my answer below.  The object is essentially making itself available as a callback to the thread class.  This is to avoid inheriting from Thread which can also be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> th = new Thread(this, threadName); //<----DOUBT

Your 2nd line is constructing a new `Thread` object with your `GetCurrentThread` class as the target (`this`) and a thread name of `"threadName"`.  Your `this` can be the target because it implements `Runnable`.  Inside of the `Thread` class, when the thread is started, it calls `Thread.run()` which does:

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

Your `GetCurrentThread` is the target since you pass `this` in to the constructor.  Really it should *not* be called `GetCurrentThread` since it isn't a thread.  Two lines after you have constructed your `Thread`, you start it running:

> th.start();

The `start()` method does the actual work of creating a separate working native thread.  The first thing the thread does is to call the `run()` method in your `GetCurrentThread` class.

As a comment, typically it is *not* recommended for a class to `start()` itself in its constructor.  There are race conditions that are inherent with this that can cause problems.  It is better to have a `start()` method on your `GetCurrentThread`

```
/** start the underlying thread */
public void start() {
   th.start();
}
```

Your main would look like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   System.out.println("Current thread name : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
   GetCurrentThread thread1 = new GetCurrentThread("1st Thread");
   thread1.start();
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the help.                                           Is "th = new Thread(this,threadName); " creating a new thread ?

Comment: "th = new Thread(this,threadName); " --- My understanding is, it creates new thread but the new thread is pointing to GetCurrentThread (in other words it is saying I am the thread called "GetCurrentThread" ), And we are giving a name to this new thread as "1st Thread". Correct me please?

Comment: As my answer states, `new Thread(this,threadName)` creates a new `Thread` object with the _target_ being your `GetCurrentThread`.  When the real `Thread` starts, it calls the `run()` method on the target.  Really you should remove the name `Thread` from the end of your class.  It isn't a `Thread`.  It is a `Runnable`.

Answer (score 1):

Well the first parameter to the constructor of `Thread` is an object whose type implements `Runnable`, which is exactly what `this` represents. Note the class declaration:

```
public class GetCurrentThread implements Runnable
```

Hence, when the thread starts the `run` method of the current instance (`this`) is executed.

Anyway, I try to avoid as much as possible this kind of code. It only leads to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
th = new Thread(this,threadName);
```

In the above line `"this" keyword` will signify the object of the class which has `implemented` Runnable Interface.

Now i will try to show you this in more detail:

```
public class A implements Runnable{

   public void run(){

                // some work
        }


}


public class B {


public static void main(String[] args){

A a = new A;
Thread t = new Thread(a);// a is an obj ref variable of class A which implements Runnable
t.start();

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` here is the object whose run method is called, in this case is an instance of the `GetCurrentThread` class. There is no guarantee that after you do `th.start()` the thread starts execution straight away. What happens here is that the main thread finishes execution before you see the output lines in the run method. Add `th.join()` after the object creation in main so you wait for the newly created thread to finish:

```
public class GetCurrentThread implements Runnable {
    Thread th;

    public Thread getThread(){
        return th;
    }

    public GetCurrentThread(String threadName) {
        th = new Thread(this, threadName); // <----DOUBT
        System.out.println("get threadname " + th.getName());
        th.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(th.getName() + " is starting.....");
        System.out.println("Current thread name : "
                + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Current thread name : "
                + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        GetCurrentThread currentThread = new GetCurrentThread("1st Thread");
        // new GetCurrentThread("2nd Thread");
        try {
            Thread thread = currentThread.getThread();
            if (thread != null) {
                thread.join();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output you get is this:

```
Current thread name : main
get threadname 1st Thread
1st Thread is starting.....
Current thread name : 1st Thread
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the constructor `Thread(Runnable target, String name)`, where first parameter `target` is any `Runnable` instance having a `run()` method.

In this particular case, `target` object is the instance of very class `GetCurrentThread`  itself (which is Runnable) where the thread is created and started. So here  `this` represents the instance of  `GetCurrentThread`

The `Runnable.run()` method is actually the **task to be performed** by a thread (which is represented by `Thread` object). If you pass a null instead of it, there wont be any task to thread to be performed and hence no `run()` method will be called.